Получение данных через обработку POST запроса
У меня есть сайт на wordpress, на нём нужно вывести результаты тестов. Платформа с тестами может отправлять на любой адрес GET и POST запросы. При GET запросе мой сайт должен ответить строкой-индентификатором, при POST запросе нужно сохранять переданные данные для последующего их вывода пользователю.
Я только недавно начал разбираться в данной теме и абсолютно не понимаю как, и через что, такое можно реализовать. Помогите пожалуйста

Почитайте, что такое get и post запросы. Как научить php обрабатывать эти запросы...

Начни с изучения что такое API  принципе и потом уже как оно реализовано на "платформе с тестами". Там наверняка и примеры реализации должны есть.

@SeVlad Примеров нет. Всё, что написано в API "вам будут отправляться POST запросы с определённой структурой". Если вы думаете что я не перебрал варианты перед тем как написать сюда, то вы сильно ошибаетесь. Мне нужно просто понять как такое реализовать...

Тогда к гадалкам.

@SeVlad XD банальный вопрос, анальный ответ
